# Prevent onclick event of appended element?

Tags: jquery, append, preventdefault

I have a page where some `onclick` code is being added to an appended element and I want to prevent the `onclick` code from firing.

Here's what I've tried:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container').append('<div class="appended" onclick="alert(\'DONT DISPLAY\')">CLICK ME</div>');
  
  // Prevent onclick
  $(document).on('click', '.appended', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Unfortunately this is not preventing the `onclick` behavior as desired

**EDIT** Should have mentioned this, but I don't have access to the code that is adding the `onclick` event to the HTML, but I am open to removing that attribute if it is possible to do that, after the fact, to an appended element.

Comment: Add `event.stopPropagation()` as well so things won't bubble up.

Comment: @nurdyguy bubbling isn't the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to remove the `onclick` attribute using `removeAttr()`

```js
$('.container').append('<div class="appended" onclick="alert(\'DONT DISPLAY\')">CLICK ME</div>');

$('.appended').removeAttr('onclick');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Doc: [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Answer (score 2):

For this to work you need to call `removeAttr()` and get rid of the `onclick` attribute:

```js
var $div = $('<div class="appended" onclick="alert(\'DONT DISPLAY\')">CLICK ME</div>').removeAttr('onclick');
$('.container').append($div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Better still, remove it from the HTML string you're actually appending - assuming you have control of that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the code that is adding the `onclick` event, sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: Then at least the code in the snippet will work for you :)

Comment: Hahah, thank you, I will upvote it since you spent the time to answer and I was not clear enough.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just to be clear though, the code I posted will still work even with your edited clarification in the question.

Comment: It does work, thank you. I just had to separate the `removeAttr` part